# Adding Icon to ListView with out a CustomListview

Tags: java, android, listview, file-manager

This has been boggling me for a while , i searched all over stackoverflow but couldn't find a similar sitiuation as mine , so what i am working on is a filemanager in android and this is my activity

```
package com.example.androidexplorer;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private List<String> item = null;
    private List<String> path = null;
    private String root;
    private TextView myPath;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myPath = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.path);

        root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

        getDir(root);

    }


    private void getDir(String dirPath) {
        myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
        item = new ArrayList<String>();
        path = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(dirPath);
        File[] files = f.listFiles();

        if (!dirPath.equals(root)) {
            item.add(root);
            path.add(root);
            item.add("../");
            path.add(f.getParent());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            File file = files[i];

            if (!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()) {
                path.add(file.getPath());
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    item.add(file.getName() + "/");
                } else {
                    item.add(file.getName());
                }
            }
        }


        ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);
        setListAdapter(fileList);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File(path.get(position));

        if (file.isDirectory())

        {
            if (file.canRead()) {
                getDir(path.get(position));
            } else {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();

            }
        } else{
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "]")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            if (file.getName().endsWith(".apk")){
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search)
                        .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "]")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
            }
            }

        }
    }
```

after this here is my activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/path"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="No Data"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

in layman terms , for example i have folder in my sdcard and when i get its path in my app i want to add an icon for it (doesnt matter from where it comes)

Comment: you don't need a custom listview, but a custom adapter

Comment: @Blackbelt could you elaborate more and if possible provide an example